# mysql select sql very slow, which one index lose

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, innodb, aggregate-functions

Helo, I have a doubt, uid column different integral can not use index, what's cause?:

please someone tell me, thanks!!!

table item_sort_20170525 have 222466057 lines,
 show create table this:

```
CREATE TABLE `item_sort_20170525` (
   `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
   `iid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
   `uid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
   `kw_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
   `platform` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
   `is_p4p` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
   `page` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
   `pos` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
   `real_pos` char(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
   `created` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `idx_keyword` (`kw_id`) USING BTREE,
   KEY `idx_iid` (`iid`,`platform`) USING BTREE,
   KEY `idx_uid` (`uid`,`platform`) USING BTREE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

if uid = 896588234 then

```
SELECT `kw_id`, COUNT(kw_id) AS `count` FROM `item_sort_20170525`
WHERE `uid` = 896588234  AND `platform` IN (12, 11) GROUP BY `kw_id` ORDER BY `kw_id` DESC LIMIT 21;
```

show explain:

```
select_type   : SIMPLE   
table         : item_sort_20170525
type          : range
possible_keys : idx_keyword,idx_uid 
key           : idx_uid 
key_len       : 9
ref           : 
rows          : 585
Extra         : Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

---

if uid = 2259613579 then

```
SELECT `kw_id`, COUNT(kw_id) AS `count` FROM `item_sort_20170525` force index(`idx_uid`)
WHERE `uid` = 2259613579   AND `platform` IN (12, 11) GROUP BY `kw_id` ORDER BY `kw_id` DESC LIMIT 21;
```

show explain:

```
select_type   : SIMPLE   
table         : item_sort_20170525
type          : ALL
possible_keys : idx_keyword,idx_uid 
key           :  
key_len       :  
ref           : 
rows          : 225015710
Extra         : Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

---

lose index(idx_uid) where uid eq a big int like 2259613579 , then use force index(idx_uid) just same failed !
this mysql optimer_trace :

```
{
   "steps": [
     {
       "join_preparation": {
         "select#": 1,
         "steps": [
           {
             "expanded_query": "/* select#1 */ select `tem_sort_20170525`.`kw_id` AS `kw_id`,count(`tem_sort_20170525`.`kw_id`) AS `count` from `tem_sort_20170525` where ((`tem_sort_20170525`.`uid` = 2259613579) and (`tem_sort_20170525`.`platform` in (12,11))) group by `tem_sort_20170525`.`kw_id` order by `tem_sort_20170525`.`kw_id` desc limit 21"
           }
         ] /* steps */
       } /* join_preparation */
     },
     {
       "join_optimization": {
         "select#": 1,
         "steps": [
           {
             "condition_processing": {
               "condition": "WHERE",
               "original_condition": "((`tem_sort_20170525`.`uid` = 2259613579) and (`tem_sort_20170525`.`platform` in (12,11)))",
               "steps": [
                 {
                   "transformation": "equality_propagation",
                   "resulting_condition": "((`tem_sort_20170525`.`platform` in (12,11)) and multiple equal(2259613579, `tem_sort_20170525`.`uid`))"
                 },
                 {
                   "transformation": "constant_propagation",
                   "resulting_condition": "((`tem_sort_20170525`.`platform` in (12,11)) and multiple equal(2259613579, `tem_sort_20170525`.`uid`))"
                 },
                 {
                   "transformation": "trivial_condition_removal",
                   "resulting_condition": "((`tem_sort_20170525`.`platform` in (12,11)) and multiple equal(2259613579, `tem_sort_20170525`.`uid`))"
                 }
               ] /* steps */
             } /* condition_processing */
           },
           {
             "table_dependencies": [
               {
                 "table": "`tem_sort_20170525`",
                 "row_may_be_null": false,
                 "map_bit": 0,
                 "depends_on_map_bits": [
                 ] /* depends_on_map_bits */
               }
             ] /* table_dependencies */
           },
           {
             "ref_optimizer_key_uses": [
               {
                 "table": "`tem_sort_20170525`",
                 "field": "uid",
                 "equals": "2259613579",
                 "null_rejecting": false
               }
             ] /* ref_optimizer_key_uses */
           },
           {
             "rows_estimation": [
               {
                 "table": "`tem_sort_20170525`",
                 "const_keys_added": {
                   "keys": [
                     "idx_keyword"
                   ] /* keys */,
                   "cause": "group_by"
                 } /* const_keys_added */,
                 "range_analysis": {
                   "table_scan": {
                     "rows": 225015710,
                     "cost": 4.61e7
                   } /* table_scan */,
                   "potential_range_indices": [
                     {
                       "index": "PRIMARY",
                       "usable": false,
                       "cause": "not_applicable"
                     },
                     {
                       "index": "idx_keyword",
                       "usable": true,
                       "key_parts": [
                         "kw_id",
                         "id"
                       ] /* key_parts */
                     },
                     {
                       "index": "idx_iid",
                       "usable": false,
                       "cause": "not_applicable"
                     },
                     {
                       "index": "idx_uid",
                       "usable": true,
                       "key_parts": [
                         "uid",
                         "platform",
                         "id"
                       ] /* key_parts */
                     }
                   ] /* potential_range_indices */,
                   "setup_range_conditions": [
                   ] /* setup_range_conditions */,
                   "group_index_range": {
                     "chosen": false,
                     "cause": "not_applicable_aggregate_function"
                   } /* group_index_range */,
                   "analyzing_range_alternatives": {
                     "range_scan_alternatives": [
                       {
                         "index": "idx_uid",
                         "ranges": [
                           "2259613579 <= uid <= 2259613579 AND 11 <= platform <= 11",
                           "2259613579 <= uid <= 2259613579 AND 12 <= platform <= 12"
                         ] /* ranges */,
                         "index_dives_for_eq_ranges": true,
                         "rowid_ordered": false,
                         "using_mrr": false,
                         "index_only": false,
                         "rows": 29,
                         "cost": 36.81,
                         "chosen": true
                       }
                     ] /* range_scan_alternatives */,
                     "analyzing_roworder_intersect": {
                       "usable": false,
                       "cause": "too_few_roworder_scans"
                     } /* analyzing_roworder_intersect */
                   } /* analyzing_range_alternatives */,
                   "chosen_range_access_summary": {
                     "range_access_plan": {
                       "type": "range_scan",
                       "index": "idx_uid",
                       "rows": 29,
                       "ranges": [
                         "2259613579 <= uid <= 2259613579 AND 11 <= platform <= 11",
                         "2259613579 <= uid <= 2259613579 AND 12 <= platform <= 12"
                       ] /* ranges */
                     } /* range_access_plan */,
                     "rows_for_plan": 29,
                     "cost_for_plan": 36.81,
                     "chosen": true
                   } /* chosen_range_access_summary */
                 } /* range_analysis */
               }
             ] /* rows_estimation */
           },
           {
             "considered_execution_plans": [
               {
                 "plan_prefix": [
                 ] /* plan_prefix */,
                 "table": "`tem_sort_20170525`",
                 "best_access_path": {
                   "considered_access_paths": [
                     {
                       "access_type": "ref",
                       "index": "idx_uid",
                       "rows": 36,
                       "cost": 43.2,
                       "chosen": true
                     },
                     {
                       "access_type": "range",
                       "rows": 22,
                       "cost": 42.61,
                       "chosen": true
                     }
                   ] /* considered_access_paths */
                 } /* best_access_path */,
                 "cost_for_plan": 42.61,
                 "rows_for_plan": 22,
                 "chosen": true
               }
             ] /* considered_execution_plans */
           },
           {
             "attaching_conditions_to_tables": {
               "original_condition": "((`tem_sort_20170525`.`uid` = 2259613579) and (`tem_sort_20170525`.`platform` in (12,11)))",
               "attached_conditions_computation": [
                 {
                   "table": "`tem_sort_20170525`",
                   "rechecking_index_usage": {
                     "recheck_reason": "low_limit",
                     "limit": 21,
                     "row_estimate": 22,
                     "range_analysis": {
                       "table_scan": {
                         "rows": 225015710,
                         "cost": 2.7e8
                       } /* table_scan */,
                       "potential_range_indices": [
                         {
                           "index": "PRIMARY",
                           "usable": false,
                           "cause": "not_applicable"
                         },
                         {
                           "index": "idx_keyword",
                           "usable": true,
                           "key_parts": [
                             "kw_id",
                             "id"
                           ] /* key_parts */
                         },
                         {
                           "index": "idx_iid",
                           "usable": false,
                           "cause": "not_applicable"
                         },
                         {
                           "index": "idx_uid",
                           "usable": false,
                           "cause": "not_applicable"
                         }
                       ] /* potential_range_indices */,
                       "setup_range_conditions": [
                       ] /* setup_range_conditions */,
                       "group_index_range": {
                         "chosen": false,
                         "cause": "cannot_do_reverse_ordering"
                       } /* group_index_range */
                     } /* range_analysis */
                   } /* rechecking_index_usage */
                 }
               ] /* attached_conditions_computation */,
               "attached_conditions_summary": [
                 {
                   "table": "`tem_sort_20170525`",
                   "attached": "((`tem_sort_20170525`.`uid` = 2259613579) and (`tem_sort_20170525`.`platform` in (12,11)))"
                 }
               ] /* attached_conditions_summary */
             } /* attaching_conditions_to_tables */
           },
           {
             "clause_processing": {
               "clause": "ORDER BY",
               "original_clause": "`tem_sort_20170525`.`kw_id` desc",
               "items": [
                 {
                   "item": "`tem_sort_20170525`.`kw_id`"
                 }
               ] /* items */,
               "resulting_clause_is_simple": true,
               "resulting_clause": "`tem_sort_20170525`.`kw_id` desc"
             } /* clause_processing */
           },
           {
             "clause_processing": {
               "clause": "GROUP BY",
               "original_clause": "`tem_sort_20170525`.`kw_id`",
               "items": [
                 {
                   "item": "`tem_sort_20170525`.`kw_id`"
                 }
               ] /* items */,
               "resulting_clause_is_simple": true,
               "resulting_clause": "`tem_sort_20170525`.`kw_id`"
             } /* clause_processing */
           },
           {
             "refine_plan": [
               {
                 "table": "`tem_sort_20170525`",
                 "access_type": "table_scan"
               }
             ] /* refine_plan */
           },
           {
             "reconsidering_access_paths_for_index_ordering": {
               "clause": "GROUP BY",
               "index_order_summary": {
                 "table": "`tem_sort_20170525`",
                 "index_provides_order": true,
                 "order_direction": "desc",
                 "index": "idx_keyword",
                 "plan_changed": true,
                 "access_type": "index_scan"
               } /* index_order_summary */
             } /* reconsidering_access_paths_for_index_ordering */
           }
         ] /* steps */
       } /* join_optimization */
     },
     {
       "join_execution": {
         "select#": 1,
         "steps": [
         ] /* steps */
       } /* join_execution */
     }
   ] /* steps */
 }
```

---

```
{
   "steps": [
     {
       "join_preparation": {
         "select#": 1,
         "steps": [
           {
             "expanded_query": "/* select#1 */ select `item_sort_20170525`.`kw_id` AS `kw_id`,count(`item_sort_20170525`.`kw_id`) AS `count` from `item_sort_20170525` FORCE INDEX (`idx_uid`) where ((`item_sort_20170525`.`uid` = 896588234) and (`item_sort_20170525`.`platform` in (12,11))) group by `item_sort_20170525`.`kw_id` order by `item_sort_20170525`.`kw_id` desc limit 21"
           }
         ] /* steps */
       } /* join_preparation */
     },
     {
       "join_optimization": {
         "select#": 1,
         "steps": [
           {
             "condition_processing": {
               "condition": "WHERE",
               "original_condition": "((`item_sort_20170525`.`uid` = 896588234) and (`item_sort_20170525`.`platform` in (12,11)))",
               "steps": [
                 {
                   "transformation": "equality_propagation",
                   "resulting_condition": "((`item_sort_20170525`.`platform` in (12,11)) and multiple equal(896588234, `item_sort_20170525`.`uid`))"
                 },
                 {
                   "transformation": "constant_propagation",
                   "resulting_condition": "((`item_sort_20170525`.`platform` in (12,11)) and multiple equal(896588234, `item_sort_20170525`.`uid`))"
                 },
                 {
                   "transformation": "trivial_condition_removal",
                   "resulting_condition": "((`item_sort_20170525`.`platform` in (12,11)) and multiple equal(896588234, `item_sort_20170525`.`uid`))"
                 }
               ] /* steps */
             } /* condition_processing */
           },
           {
             "table_dependencies": [
               {
                 "table": "`item_sort_20170525` FORCE INDEX (`idx_uid`)",
                 "row_may_be_null": false,
                 "map_bit": 0,
                 "depends_on_map_bits": [
                 ] /* depends_on_map_bits */
               }
             ] /* table_dependencies */
           },
           {
             "ref_optimizer_key_uses": [
               {
                 "table": "`item_sort_20170525` FORCE INDEX (`idx_uid`)",
                 "field": "uid",
                 "equals": "896588234",
                 "null_rejecting": false
               }
             ] /* ref_optimizer_key_uses */
           },
           {
             "rows_estimation": [
               {
                 "table": "`item_sort_20170525` FORCE INDEX (`idx_uid`)",
                 "const_keys_added": {
                   "keys": [
                     "idx_keyword"
                   ] /* keys */,
                   "cause": "group_by"
                 } /* const_keys_added */,
                 "range_analysis": {
                   "table_scan": {
                     "rows": 225015710,
                     "cost": 2e308
                   } /* table_scan */,
                   "potential_range_indices": [
                     {
                       "index": "PRIMARY",
                       "usable": false,
                       "cause": "not_applicable"
                     },
                     {
                       "index": "idx_keyword",
                       "usable": false,
                       "cause": "not_applicable"
                     },
                     {
                       "index": "idx_iid",
                       "usable": false,
                       "cause": "not_applicable"
                     },
                     {
                       "index": "idx_uid",
                       "usable": true,
                       "key_parts": [
                         "uid",
                         "platform",
                         "id"
                       ] /* key_parts */
                     }
                   ] /* potential_range_indices */,
                   "setup_range_conditions": [
                   ] /* setup_range_conditions */,
                   "group_index_range": {
                     "chosen": false,
                     "cause": "not_applicable_aggregate_function"
                   } /* group_index_range */,
                   "analyzing_range_alternatives": {
                     "range_scan_alternatives": [
                       {
                         "index": "idx_uid",
                         "ranges": [
                           "896588234 <= uid <= 896588234 AND 11 <= platform <= 11",
                           "896588234 <= uid <= 896588234 AND 12 <= platform <= 12"
                         ] /* ranges */,
                         "index_dives_for_eq_ranges": true,
                         "rowid_ordered": false,
                         "using_mrr": false,
                         "index_only": false,
                         "rows": 585,
                         "cost": 704.01,
                         "chosen": true
                       }
                     ] /* range_scan_alternatives */,
                     "analyzing_roworder_intersect": {
                       "usable": false,
                       "cause": "too_few_roworder_scans"
                     } /* analyzing_roworder_intersect */
                   } /* analyzing_range_alternatives */,
                   "chosen_range_access_summary": {
                     "range_access_plan": {
                       "type": "range_scan",
                       "index": "idx_uid",
                       "rows": 585,
                       "ranges": [
                         "896588234 <= uid <= 896588234 AND 11 <= platform <= 11",
                         "896588234 <= uid <= 896588234 AND 12 <= platform <= 12"
                       ] /* ranges */
                     } /* range_access_plan */,
                     "rows_for_plan": 585,
                     "cost_for_plan": 704.01,
                     "chosen": true
                   } /* chosen_range_access_summary */
                 } /* range_analysis */
               }
             ] /* rows_estimation */
           },
           {
             "considered_execution_plans": [
               {
                 "plan_prefix": [
                 ] /* plan_prefix */,
                 "table": "`item_sort_20170525` FORCE INDEX (`idx_uid`)",
                 "best_access_path": {
                   "considered_access_paths": [
                     {
                       "access_type": "ref",
                       "index": "idx_uid",
                       "rows": 585,
                       "cost": 702,
                       "chosen": true
                     },
                     {
                       "access_type": "range",
                       "rows": 439,
                       "cost": 821.01,
                       "chosen": false
                     }
                   ] /* considered_access_paths */
                 } /* best_access_path */,
                 "cost_for_plan": 702,
                 "rows_for_plan": 585,
                 "chosen": true
               }
             ] /* considered_execution_plans */
           },
           {
             "attaching_conditions_to_tables": {
               "original_condition": "((`item_sort_20170525`.`uid` = 896588234) and (`item_sort_20170525`.`platform` in (12,11)))",
               "attached_conditions_computation": [
                 {
                   "access_type_changed": {
                     "table": "`item_sort_20170525` FORCE INDEX (`idx_uid`)",
                     "index": "idx_uid",
                     "old_type": "ref",
                     "new_type": "range",
                     "cause": "uses_more_keyparts"
                   } /* access_type_changed */
                 }
               ] /* attached_conditions_computation */,
               "attached_conditions_summary": [
                 {
                   "table": "`item_sort_20170525` FORCE INDEX (`idx_uid`)",
                   "attached": "((`item_sort_20170525`.`uid` = 896588234) and (`item_sort_20170525`.`platform` in (12,11)))"
                 }
               ] /* attached_conditions_summary */
             } /* attaching_conditions_to_tables */
           },
           {
             "clause_processing": {
               "clause": "ORDER BY",
               "original_clause": "`item_sort_20170525`.`kw_id` desc",
               "items": [
                 {
                   "item": "`item_sort_20170525`.`kw_id`"
                 }
               ] /* items */,
               "resulting_clause_is_simple": true,
               "resulting_clause": "`item_sort_20170525`.`kw_id` desc"
             } /* clause_processing */
           },
           {
             "clause_processing": {
               "clause": "GROUP BY",
               "original_clause": "`item_sort_20170525`.`kw_id`",
               "items": [
                 {
                   "item": "`item_sort_20170525`.`kw_id`"
                 }
               ] /* items */,
               "resulting_clause_is_simple": true,
               "resulting_clause": "`item_sort_20170525`.`kw_id`"
             } /* clause_processing */
           },
           {
             "refine_plan": [
               {
                 "table": "`item_sort_20170525` FORCE INDEX (`idx_uid`)",
                 "pushed_index_condition": "((`item_sort_20170525`.`uid` = 896588234) and (`item_sort_20170525`.`platform` in (12,11)))",
                 "table_condition_attached": null,
                 "access_type": "range"
               }
             ] /* refine_plan */
           }
         ] /* steps */
       } /* join_optimization */
     },
     {
       "join_execution": {
         "select#": 1,
         "steps": [
           {
             "creating_tmp_table": {
               "tmp_table_info": {
                 "table": "intermediate_tmp_table",
                 "row_length": 13,
                 "key_length": 4,
                 "unique_constraint": false,
                 "location": "memory (heap)",
                 "row_limit_estimate": 161319
               } /* tmp_table_info */
             } /* creating_tmp_table */
           },
           {
             "filesort_information": [
               {
                 "direction": "desc",
                 "table": "intermediate_tmp_table",
                 "field": "kw_id"
               }
             ] /* filesort_information */,
             "filesort_priority_queue_optimization": {
               "limit": 21,
               "rows_estimate": 540,
               "row_size": 12,
               "memory_available": 720896,
               "chosen": true
             } /* filesort_priority_queue_optimization */,
             "filesort_execution": [
             ] /* filesort_execution */,
             "filesort_summary": {
               "rows": 22,
               "examined_rows": 530,
               "number_of_tmp_files": 0,
               "sort_buffer_size": 440,
               "sort_mode": "<sort_key, rowid>"
             } /* filesort_summary */
           }
         ] /* steps */
       } /* join_execution */
     }
   ] /* steps */
 }
```

Comment: How many rows in the table?  How many have `uid` = 2259613579?

Answer (score 1):

Your query:

```
 SELECT `kw_id`, COUNT(kw_id) AS `count` 
   FROM `item_sort_20170525`
  WHERE `uid` = 896588234
    AND `platform` IN (12, 11)
  GROUP BY `kw_id`
  ORDER BY `kw_id` DESC
  LIMIT 21;
```

Here you have two filtering criteria: `uid` equality and `platform` in a set.
Then you have a grouping criterion that's also a reverse ordering criterion.

Can you change the `platform` criterion from a set to a range? If so, do it. `platform BETWEEN 11 AND 12`. It does look like the query planner figured that one out on its own, though.

Then try a compound index that starts with equality criteria, then has range criteria, then has grouping criteria. In this case:

```
(uid, platform, kw_id)
```

That *should* allow your query to be satisfied from an index range scan. Adding `kw_id` to the index makes it a *covering* index, meaning everything required by the query can be satisfied by the index. It also may allow a reverse range scan to produce the `DESC` ordering.

Also, because you have declared `kw_id` as `NOT NULL`, you can use `COUNT(*)` in place of `COUNT(kw_id)`. That may help, but probably not much.

**Pro tip**: Always format your queries so your selection, filtering, grouping, and ordering criteria jump out at you when you look at them. The more rows you have in your tables, the more important this becomes.

Comment: thank you very much, and i have a other question: why the big number do not use index ? is't the big integer number

Answer (score 1):

O.Jones answer is very good.  There are two more things you can try:

```
SELECT kw_id, SUM(cnt)
FROM ((SELECT `kw_id`, COUNT(*) AS cnt
       FROM `item_sort_20170525`
       WHERE `uid` = 896588234 AND `platform` = 11
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT `kw_id`, COUNT(*) AS cnt
       FROM `item_sort_20170525`
       WHERE `uid` = 896588234 AND `platform` = 12
      )
     ) i
GROUP BY `kw_id`
ORDER BY `kw_id` DESC
LIMIT 21;
```

You want the same index, `item_sort_20170525(uid, platform, kw_id)`.  MySQL should be able to remove the file sort for the inner group by.  So, if there are not very many `kw_id`s, then the outer `group by` should not be very expensive.

Another option is to use a correlated subquery.  This assumes that you have a list of `kw_id`s somewhere.  The query looks like

```
select kw_id,
       (select count(*)
        from `item_sort_20170525` i
        where i.kw_id = k.kw_id and `uid` = 896588234 and
              `platform` in (11, 12)
       ) as cnt
from kw
order by kw.kw_id desc;
```

This version will work will if most/all `kw_id`s have at least one matching row in the items table.  For this query, you want an index on  `item_sort_20170525(kw_id, uid, platform)`.

Comment: With a gigarow-scale table, it's worth trying all kinds of stuff to get efficient queries! Good additions.

Comment: thank you very much, and i have a other question:
why the big number do not use index ? is't the big integer number